# Canvas - transforming mouse coordinates on window resize

Tags: javascript, canvas, transformation

I'm working on a canvas project which includes some drag and drop functionality for some bitmap images on the canvas. I'm having trouble selecting images after the canvas has been resized.

At the minute what i've got is working fine for when the canvas is at it's default dimensions.

I'm drawing all my graphics to a canvas then drawing that image to another canvas and displaying that.

So I want to be able to 'select' an image on the canvas.

Obviously I do this by comparing the mouse coordinates with the coordinates of the object.

```
   mouseX = mouse.x - window.offsetLeft; //I'm accounting for the offset
```

I'm then multiplying the mouse coordinates by (theVisibleCanvas.width / originalCanvas.width) to account for the scaling of the canvas.

This all works fine for when the window is maximized ( the default dimensions) but once I've resized the window the coordinates start getting further and further out.

Can anyone point out any steps involved in translating mouse coordinates in relation to the canvas resizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of you provided has little to do with canvas as it uses the offset of the window rather than the offset of the canvas.

To get the coordinates from the mouse adjusted to canvas you can use something like this:

```
function getXY(canvas, event){

    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), /// get absolute rect. of canvas
        x = event.clientX - rect.left,         /// adjust for x
        y = event.clientY - rect.top;          /// adjust for y

    return {x:x, y:y};                         /// return object
}
```

Now you can call this:

```
var pos = getXY(myCanvasElement, theEvent);
console.log(pos.x, pos.y);   /// use the pos object for something
```

Of course, `myCanvasElement` is a reference to your actual canvas element and `theEvent` provided by the callback.